# Logstash parsing unix time in milliseconds since epoch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I am trying to match **unix time in milliseconds since epoch** in logstash/grok using the UNIX_MS pattern and I am getting :

> pattern %{UNIX_MS:timestamp} not defined

The `UNIX_MS` is defined [Logstash Date Log](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date), and when I run with `--configtest`, the test passes, so I would expect this to work.

Example input: `1415731504.54126,metric1,130`

My `.conf`:

```
filter {
    grok {
     match => [ "message", "%{UNIX_MS:timestamp},%{WORD:metric_type},%{BASE16FLOAT:value}" ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNIX_MS is marked on that pages as a "special exception".  You can see in the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) that it doesn't work in a "match".

%{NUMBER:timestamp} will give you the field.

Comment: So what does "special exception" means? That it is documented but does not work? The doc says "The following format literals exist to help you save time and ensure correctness of date parsing."

Comment: You're quoting documentation on the 'date' filter.  Why would you expect the documentation to apply to the 'grok' filter?

Comment: Ohh,I see. I thought that it applies to both `date` and `grok` filter. Thanks.